# How do you use your interface's private methods?

Tags: java, oop, interface, private, access-modifiers

I'm having trouble using a private method I had implemented within my interface.

I implemented a `print(string, list)` method privately in my `RequestData` interface, to hide implementation as I don't want it to be called except by the class' other print methods - but I included it in the interface because it's going to be the same with each implementing class.

Problem is, when I try to use the `print` method from my `FundingRequests`, which implements the `RequestData` interface, it shows the error - the `print` method's access in the `RequestData` interface is private, so it can't be found.

Well... how are you supposed to use an interface's private methods if they are not accessible from within the implementing classes?

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding Interfaces?

Interface:

```
package com.landbay.datamodel.data;

import java.util.List;

public interface RequestData<E> {

    void add(E newRequest);

    List<E> getRequests();

    List<E> getFulfilledRequests();

    List<E> getUnfulfilledRequests();

    void printRequests();

    void printFulfilledRequests();

    void printUnfulfilledRequests();

    private void print(String listTitle, List<E> listToPrint) {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        string.append(listTitle);

        for (E request : listToPrint) {
            string.append("\n").append(request);
        }

        System.out.println(string);
    }

}
```

Offending class & methods:

```
public class FundingRequests implements RequestData<FundingRequest> {
        private TreeSet<FundingRequest> requests;

        FundingRequests() {
            this.requests = new TreeSet<>();
        }

        ...

        @Override
        public void printRequests() {
            print("",new ArrayList<>(requests));
        }

}
```

Comment: Private methods in interfaces are not meant to be used by implementing classes and in fact cannot be used by nature of being `private`. They were added to make it easier to implement `static` and `default` interface methods.

Comment: @Slaw's on it, private methods are for use within the class, protected (the default scope) members are visible to sub-classes, and public scope is what you need if you want visibility to outside classes.

Comment: @Slaw okay, that's interesting - thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private methods were provided as a feature to Java interfaces to help write default methods in interfaces without re-using code. They were not intended to be used for implementation inheritance.

If you want to inherit and use implemented methods, such as what you attempted here:

```
@Override
public void printRequests() {
    print("",new ArrayList<>(requests));
}
```

you want to either implement the method in a super class and extend that class, or implement the method as a default method in an interface. Using a super class would be the more conventional way to do this.

Using the code you provided, you could do something like this:

```
class Printer {

    protected void print(String listTitle, List<E> listToPrint) {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        string.append(listTitle);

        for (E request : listToPrint) {
            string.append("\n").append(request);
        }
}
```

then extend that class:

```
public class FundingRequests extends Printer implements RequestData<FundingRequest> {
        private TreeSet<FundingRequest> requests;

        FundingRequests() {
            this.requests = new TreeSet<>();
        }

        ...

        @Override
        public void printRequests() {
            print("",new ArrayList<>(requests));
        }

}
```

although that would limit your class to only extending that class. The better pattern would be to implement that method as a public static method in a class, then use it, like this:

```
class Printer {

    public static void print(String listTitle, List<E> listToPrint) {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        string.append(listTitle);

        for (E request : listToPrint) {
            string.append("\n").append(request);
        }
    }
}
```

then use the method:

```
public class FundingRequests implements RequestData<FundingRequest> {
    private TreeSet<FundingRequest> requests;

    FundingRequests() {
        this.requests = new TreeSet<>();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void printRequests() {
        Printer.print("",new ArrayList<>(requests));
    }
}
```

or, if you really want to go crazy, you can pull this off with an abstract class:

```
abstract class RequestData<E> {

    abstract void add(E newRequest);

    abstract List<E> getRequests();

    abstract List<E> getFulfilledRequests();

    abstract List<E> getUnfulfilledRequests();

    abstract void printRequests();

    abstract void printFulfilledRequests();

    abstract void printUnfulfilledRequests();

    protected void print(String listTitle, List<E> listToPrint) {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        string.append(listTitle);

        for (E request : listToPrint) {
            string.append("\n").append(request);
        }

        System.out.println(string);
    }

}
```

then extend that class:

```
public class FundingRequests extends RequestData<FundingRequest> {
        private TreeSet<FundingRequest> requests;

        FundingRequests() {
            this.requests = new TreeSet<>();
        }

        // implement the abstract methods

        @Override
        public void printRequests() {
            print("",new ArrayList<>(requests));
        }

}
```

Comment: So, should I change the interface to an abstract class and extend from it?

Comment: an abstract class is used to declare methods that are implemented in different ways by classes that extend it. if you want to distribute the method implementation to other classes, simply implement the method, in a class, with a public or protected scope, then extend that class.

Comment: My understanding of the abstract class is that like an interface it allows for you to specify methods which must be implemented but may be done so in different ways, but you are also able to define concrete methods (such as my print method), so wouldn't an abstract class be perfect? Of course - I could create another method with just that singular method and extend from it while implementing my interface separately but isn't that an extra, unnecessary step?

Comment: the problem with abstract classes is that they limit extending classes to only extend that class. although this is possible, that did not seem like your intent since you are writing up an interface. i updated my answer with two alternative examples.

Comment: Many thanks. I like your solution - I don't know why it wasn't obvious to me. One problem, the Printer class obviously doesn't recognise the 'E' parameter type. How to resolve that, given that the lists to be printed contain different objects? Will I need overloaded methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pull out that `print()` method totally, or make it a nested static class.

```
public interface RequestData<E> {

    void add(E newRequest);

    List<E> getRequests();

    List<E> getFulfilledRequests();

    List<E> getUnfulfilledRequests();

    void printRequests();

    void printFulfilledRequests();

    void printUnfulfilledRequests();

    public static final class Printer {
        protected static <E> void print(String listTitle, List<E> listToPrint) {
            StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
            string.append(listTitle);

            for (E request : listToPrint) {
                string.append("\n").append(request);
            }

            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}


public class FundingRequests implements RequestData<FundingRequest> {
    private TreeSet<FundingRequest> requests;

    FundingRequests() {
        this.requests = new TreeSet<>();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void printRequests() {
        Printer.print("",new ArrayList<>(requests));
    }
}
```

This allows you to keep `print()` at `protected` accessibility, but it would expose `Printer` nested static class, which does nothing from a `public` perspective. If it is fine to make the method `public`, you can simply define that method as a `public static` (i.e. an utility) method.

Answer (score -2):

You should use protected modifiers. Private methods are only accessible from the same class, not by child classes.

Comment: Can you have protected methods in an interface?

Comment: OP is trying to do this with an interface which cannot have `protected` methods.